# Azure VMs Ubuntu , How to enable SSH port(22) in ubuntu firewall Now I am not able to get access my VM using SSH

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, azure, ubuntu-16.04, ufw

I have ubuntu VM running in azure.

By mistake, I enable ubuntu firewall using this command

sudo ufw enable

and I forgot to enable SSH port(22) in ubuntu firewall

Now I am not able to get access my VM using SSH.

What to do now

Answer (score 6):

You could use [Linux Custom Script Extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/CustomScript) to disable Ubuntu firewall on your VM.

Firstly, you need write a script name as `script.sh`. Add following line to your script.

```
ufw disable
```

Notes: Don't need add sudo on your script.

Also, you could open port 22 on firewall, just modify your script like below:

```
ufw allow 22
```

On Azure Portal, find Custom Script Extension. `Your resource group-->your VM-->Extensions-->Add-->Custom Script For Linux`
[image]

After the extension is installed successful, you could ssh to your VM.

Update:

You could uninstall the extension on Azure Portal and execute the following script again.

```
ufw disable
ufw status
```

Please ensure firewall is `inactive`. You could check log on Portal.
[image]

Also, you could use `telnet` to check whether port 22 is listening.

```
telnet IP 22
```

When the firewall is disabled, but you could not ssh to your VM, you had better check your Azure NSG, please ensure port 22 is added to inbound rules.

Comment: I had the same issue and this helped me "unlock" the instance . Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easier way is to headover to Azure Portal > Your VM > Support + Troubleshooting > [Serial Console](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/virtual-machine-serial-console-access/). It comes with Windows and Linux VMs and simply disable it there

Comment: Much easier than @Shui shengbao's solution (which of course also works, it's just jumping through several hoops to achieve the same effect)